# Resize ImageView with Pinch

Tags: android, imageview, gesture

I followed the [guideline I found in the Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)

But The Problem is It's only moving and zooming inside the image view bounds. What I want is to resize the image view with two finger gesture. And it should get bigger or smaller according to the pinch.I have been googling about resizing the whole day and couldn't figure it out. All the tutorial only point me to zooming inside ImageView instead of resizing.
 Following is my Custom Image View code resulted from the blog.

```
public class InteractableImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {

  private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
  private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
  private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
  private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
  private float mPosX;
  private float mPosY;

  private float mLastTouchX;
  private float mLastTouchY;

  public InteractableImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
  }

  public InteractableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
  }

  public InteractableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
  }

  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
      }

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
        if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
          final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
          final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

          mPosX += dx;
          mPosY += dy;

          invalidate();
        }

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        break;
      }

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
      }

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
      }

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
          // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
          // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
          final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
          mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
          mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
          mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
  }

  private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
      mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

      // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
      mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

      invalidate();
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

In your xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.yourpackagename.CustomImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The CustomImageView,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by yeminhtut on 10/21/15.
 */
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix2 = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    float[] lastEvent;
    float d;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
                mode = NONE;
                break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    // ...
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                            - start.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null) {
                        float newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                                view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
        // Perform the transformation
        fixing();
        view.setImageMatrix(savedMatrix2);

        return true; // indicate event was handled

    }
    public void fixing()
        {

        float[] value = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(value);

        float[] savedValue = new float[9];
        savedMatrix2.getValues(savedValue);

        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();

        Drawable d = this.getDrawable();
        if (d == null)  return;
        int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
        int scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[4]);

// don't let the image go outside
        if (value[2] > width-1)
            value[2] = width-10;
        else if (value[5] > height - 1)
            value[5] = height - 10;
        else if (value[2] < -(scaleWidth-1))
            value[2] = -(scaleWidth-10);
        else if (value[5] < -(scaleHeight-1))
            value[5] = -(scaleHeight-10);

        matrix.setValues(value);
        savedMatrix2.set(matrix);
    }
    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x/2, y/2);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps :).
Happy coding.

Comment: This is amazing. just one issue with code. when i touch first time on image view it enlarges too much. How to keep image to its original size on first touch?

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily achieved with a lib : [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

All you have to do is :

```
new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
```

and you will have gesture detection implemented on your ImageView